# Javascript Fluorescent Light Flickering On Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if any Javascript/jquery geniuses could help me.

As I have no skills in javascript.

I wanted to have an image start off blank/blacked out and then over 5 seconds or so the image flickers on, similar to a fluorescent light fixture turning on.

I could do this in Flash easily but I want support for the ipad.

Any takers... I would be forever in debted :)

Comment: Just in case anybody's wondering, here's a video of fluorescent lights flickering http://j.mp/pFOjNd BTW +1 for a neat challenge - I eagerly await the answer too!  The effect you're talking about, I think it's also seen in some light fixtures in dark video games like Doom 3.

Answer (score 2):

This is my first attempt at but you could chain events like this:

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/300" id="kitten">

    $('#kitten').hide().delay(5000).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(150).fadeOut(150).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(250).fadeOut(250).fadeIn(100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/malcolmb/gbMVU/1/

You can extend this by using a custom jQuery animation http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: That's close I will try and play with some opacity settings to see if that helps. Maybe a white flash towards the end... I will post my results. Thank you :)